# Combine json files and preserve format in R

Tags: json, r

I have two json files in the exact format as below.  My goal is to combine them and keep the exact same format  - just basically stack one on top of the other.

I have tried the following but this does not correctly combine both files and preserve the format as both files are bracketed with `[ ]` separately.  How does one combine and keep only one pair of brackets around the entire file?

```
files <- c("test.json","test2.json")
jsonl <- lapply(files, function(f) fromJSON(file = f))
jsonc <- toJSON(jsonl)
write(jsonc, file = "two.json")
```

Are there any better solutions in R?

`test.json`:

```
[
  {
    "vendor": 0,
    "startTime": 4380,
    "endTime": 4445
  },
  {
    "vendor": 0,
    "startTime": 4448,
    "endTime": 4453
  },
  {
    "vendor": 0,
    "startTime": 4696,
    "endTime": 4880
  }
]
```

undesired output:

```
[
  [
    {"vendor":0,"startTime":4380,"endTime":4445},
    {"vendor":0,"startTime":4448,"endTime":4453},
    {"vendor":0,"startTime":4696,"endTime":4880}],

    [{"vendor":0,"startTime":4380,"endTime":4445},
      {"vendor":0,"startTime":4448,"endTime":4453},
      {"vendor":0,"startTime":4696,"endTime":4880}
  ]
]
```

desired output:

```
  [
    {"vendor":0,"startTime":4380,"endTime":4445},
    {"vendor":0,"startTime":4448,"endTime":4453},
    {"vendor":0,"startTime":4696,"endTime":4880},
    {"vendor":0,"startTime":4380,"endTime":4445},
    {"vendor":0,"startTime":4448,"endTime":4453},
    {"vendor":0,"startTime":4696,"endTime":4880}
  ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join them before writing using `rbind`

```
files <- c("test.json","test2.json")
jsonl <- do.call("rbind", lapply(files, function(f) fromJSON(f)))
write(toJSON(jsonl), file = "two.json")
```